# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+2y+3}{x+2y-3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+2y+3}{x+2y-3}
$$
I don't know where to start with it.

I know it's not an exact first order ODE, nor homogeneous, nor linear, and I don't think it's separable. Maybe a substitution?

Comment: Just a suggestion: $\frac{x+2y+3}{x+2y-3}=1+\frac{6}{x+2y-3}$. I don't know if it would help, but I guess you could look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $u=x+2y$.  Then
$$\frac{du}{dx}=1+2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
and the DE becomes
$$\frac{du}{dx}=1+2\frac{u+3}{u-3}$$
which is separable.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = -\dfrac{x+1}{2} - 2 W\left(c e^{-3x/4}\right)$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function and $c$ an arbitrary constant.